# CSS/Jquery to display child element after parent element

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs

I'm trying to create tabbed navigation based on my current HTML structure. Basically, I want to be able to show book titles as tabs and book details BELOW the tabs. Like this:

[image: This is what I want]

or this: http://jsfiddle.net/syahrasi/Us8uc/

Modifying the HTML structure **is not an option**. I'm looking for a pure CSS solution, or - if that's not possible - CSS combined with jquery

In my current implementation (see below), when you click on a "book title" tab the next tab is pushed to the right. I'm looking for a solution that displays the book content below the tabs - without pushing the next tab to the right.

**What I currently have:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.book-content').hide();
});

$('.btn').click(function(e) {
    $('.book-content').hide();
   $(this).closest('.book').find('.book-content').slideToggle('fast');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
body{
 background-color: grey;
}
.books{
 background-color: white;
}
.book{
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 background-color: lightblue;
}
.hide{
 display: none;
}
.active{
 background-color:#F7778F;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stackoverflow.css">
</head>
<body>

 <div class="books"> BOOKS <br/>
  <div class="book">
   <div class="book-title"><a href="" class="btn">Book 1</a></div>
   <div class="book-content">
    <div class="book-description">Description Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="book-author">Author Lorem ipsum</div>
   </div>
   
  </div>
  <div class="book active">
   <div class="book-title"><a href="" class="btn">Book 2</a></div>
   <div class="book-content">
    <div class="book-description">Description Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="book-author">Author Lorem ipsum</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="book">
   <div class="book-title"><a href="" class="btn">Book 3</a></div>
   <div class="book-content hide">
    <div class="book-description">Description Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="book-author">Author Lorem ipsum</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="stackoverflow.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: @void I added a bit more detail to my question

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.book-content').hide();
});

$('.btn').click(function(e) {
    if(!$(this).closest('.book').find('.book-content:visible').length) 
    {
    $('.book-content').slideUp('fast');
   $(this).closest('.book').find('.book-content').slideDown('fast');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
body{
 background-color: grey;
}
.books{
 background-color: white;
}
.book{
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 background-color: lightblue;
}
.hide{
 display: none;
}
.active{
 background-color:#F7778F;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stackoverflow.css">
</head>
<body>

 <div class="books"> BOOKS <br/>
  <div class="book">
   <div class="book-title"><a href="" class="btn">Book 1</a></div>
   <div class="book-content">
    <div class="book-description">Description Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="book-author">Author Lorem ipsum</div>
   </div>
   
  </div>
  <div class="book active">
   <div class="book-title"><a href="" class="btn">Book 2</a></div>
   <div class="book-content">
    <div class="book-description">Description Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="book-author">Author Lorem ipsum</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="book">
   <div class="book-title"><a href="" class="btn">Book 3</a></div>
   <div class="book-content hide">
    <div class="book-description">Description Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="book-author">Author Lorem ipsum</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="stackoverflow.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks but this still pushes the other tabs to the right. I need to display the content below all the tabs. So when a user clicks a tab the other tabs will remain in their place.

Answer (score 0):

Below solution will solve your problem without modifying html

CSS:

```
 body{background-color: grey;}
.books{background-color: white !important;}
.book{display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;background-color: lightblue;}
.hide,.book-content{display: none;}
.active{background-color:#F7778F;}
.cls_dsp{position: absolute;left: 8px !important;;}
.cls_ind{z-index:2;position:relative;}
```

Jquery:

```
$('.book').removeClass('active');
$(document).on('click','.btn',function() {
$('.btn').parent().next().hide();        
$('.btn').removeClass('active');     
$(this).addClass('active'); 
$(this).parent().css('width',$(this).width());
$(this).parent().next().addClass('active').show();    
$(this).parent().parent().addClass('books cls_dsp');     
$('.book-title').addClass('cls_ind');
if ($(this).parent().parent().prev().get(0).tagName!='BR'){
$(this).parent().parent().removeClass('cls_ind'); 
$(this).parent().css(
'left',$(this).parent().parent().prev().children(1).position().left+
$(this).parent().parent().prev().first().width()+8);  
 $(this).parent().parent().nextAll().removeClass('cls_dsp').addClass('cls_ind');     
 $(this).parent().parent().nextAll().css(
 'left',$(this).parent().position().left+$(this).parent().width()+8)}
 else{ 
 $(this).parent().parent().nextAll().removeClass('cls_dsp').addClass('cls_ind' );         
 $(this).parent().parent().nextAll().css('left',
 $(this).parent().parent().position().left+$(this).parent().width())}
 $(this).parent().parent().nextAll().children(1).css('left','0');  
 $(this).parent().parent().parent().css('height',
 $(this).parent().parent().height()+20+'px')
});
```

Here is the **JSFIddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/7m6oz2tv/3/

Eventhough this solution solved the problem, need help to improve the above coding style.